# RestKit: confused as to how to setup a POST

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I have managed to GET objects and to POST a new object to the server, but the POST generates an error on the iPhone.

Here is my setup:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMappingFoo pathPattern:@"/foos" keyPath:@"foos" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]; // Works well for GET

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[entityMappingFoo inverseMapping]  objectClass:[Foo class] rootKeyPath:@"foo"]; // Client --> Server works
```

The problem is (I think) that:

- when I GET, the back-end expects the JSON to have a plural key: `{"foos":[...]}` (which makes sense since there might be several objects)
- when I POST one object, RestKit expects the answer from the back-end to be singular: `{"foo":...}`. Yet, since it uses the same responseDescriptor as for GET, it gets a plural and it is lost.

If I replace `keyPath:@"foos"` by `keyPath:@"foo"` in `responseDescriptor` my POST works... but not my GET.

How do I reconcile the two?

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Basically you just need to create multiple response descriptors to cover the different cases. You can use the same mapping in each, but RestKit needs to know what to look for when processing a response and your 2 cases are different.

Comment: Thank you Wain. How do you do this though? I thought it would be something like that and I tried to create another response descriptor, but I did not find how to tell postObject to use this additional descriptor instead of the original one (since the path itself is /foos in both cases). There does not seem to be a hook to do that, is there?

Comment: I found a solution which is to use the exact statusCode (201 for Created vs 200 for a normal GET) for each responseDescriptor. Feels weird though to have to do this. I am under the impression I must be missing something obvious...